# Putting text shadow on a UIButton text label

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` on which I am putting a text label. I want to change the color of the text and also put a shadow 1 pixel away from the text, to give it a nice 3D kind of view. How would I do this?

Comment: ...and so you looked at the [`UILabel` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html), saw [`textColor`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW14) and [`shadowOffset`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW2), and now what's the problem you're having?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to change the color of the text ...

[`-[UILabel setTextColor:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW14)

> ... and also put some shadow ...

[`-[UILabel setShadowColor:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW1)

> ... 1 pix away from the text

[`-[UILabel setShadowOffset:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006797-CH3-SW2)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in IB with the Text Color, Shadow Color and Shadow Offset controls in the attributes inspector.